# Style SQL query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

When I am debugging my program I have many big SQL queries as output at the bottom and I analyze them. Would it be possible to style query like :

`SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN profile ON users.id = profile.id WHERE user_id = 2` to

```
SELECT * FROM users 
LEFT JOIN profile 
ON users.id = profile.id
WHERE user_id = 2
```

so it would be easier to follow the query? Is there anything I could do without lots of code in PHP? Or maybe there's jQuery plugin for that?

Comment: Is there actually a need for the original query to be on one line in the source code rather than having natural indentation and line breaks? Maybe this is a limitation of MySQL or the PHP library, as I don't use it regularly, but I can't find a reference for such. If it is possible, it would be far better to fix your source code so you have the benefit of formatting while editing the code as well as when debugging it.

Comment: @IMSoP there is no such limitation in PHP

Comment: @Mike Thanks. I've seen a lot of people squeezing their queries onto one line like this, so thought perhaps there was some good reason for it. It seems really natural to me to format SQL queries onto multiple lines as I write them, just like I would any other code.

Comment: @IMSoP I agree. I try to break mine up as much as I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [sql-formatter](http://jdorn.github.com/sql-formatter/) might just do what you need. It is a pretty simple PHP class.

The GitHub repository is here: https://github.com/jdorn/sql-formatter

Answer (score 2):

here [sql beautifier](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm)
That beautify queries , and your query after beeing beautified will look like this.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM   users
    LEFT JOIN profile
          ON users.id = profile.id
 WHERE  user_id = 2
```

Its better to read quickly and understand all steps.